# Installing DNS, DHCP, Apache on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: apache2, dns, bind

Is it possible to use Ubuntu Desktop to Install DNS, Apache, DHCP services and so on for learning purposes ? By the by, I like Ubuntu desktop rather than Using Server and dont want to install GUI to Server. Enlighten me on this.

Comment: If you don't want a GUI and want server-related applications, why not just use Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Installing all these applications will involve typing commands into terminal regardless. You should experiment with Ubuntu Server as it's more efficient on resources.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe... Sorry friend ! I made a mistake in my question. Already altered. It was '..don't want to install GUI to Desktop.' But it should be read as 'Sever' instead of 'Dekstop'. That is why you thought I don't want GUI. I like Desktop GUI and still wants to install above mentioned services. don't want install GUI to server because I have limited internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can; it's quite usual to do install Apache for development purposes. (DNS and DHCP not so much because those functions are generally handled by dedicated infrastructure.) Just pretend that you have the Server edition and follow the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/). The difference between the Desktop and Server edition consists mainly in the selection of packages which are installed by default.

Just a recommendation: If you install DHCP be sure to think carefully beforehand how DHCP will work on your network(s).